# No instant preview anymore for tikz pictures in LyX; reset previews?

Tags: latex, tikz, lyx

I'm inserting figures into my LyX document by adding a graphics float, then an instant preview window inside the float, and a tex code window inside of that preview window. Here I put my tikz code.
It has been working fine until I changed the code of one figure. Since then, all figures are not anymore shown as previews in LyX. I undid the changes, deleted the LyX temp folders, but previews are not showing up. Compiling the document, however, works just fine.

When I slightly modify the tikz code of a figure, e.g. by adding a `%` at the and of any line, this figure can be previewed again. I'd rather not add a `%` to every figure in the document - is there any way to reset all previews in the LyX document without deleting the tikz code?

Comment: Does it work if you go to Tools > Preferences > Display and change "Instant preview" to "off", click OK. Then go back and turn it back on? Even if that works, it's still annoying, but perhaps less annoying that your workaround for each figure?

Comment: Whoever gave this post a "-1", could you please always add a comment explaining *why*? How is zip supposed to improve their questions in the future if there is no constructive feedback? I found the question to be clearly explained -> +1.

Comment: Thanks scottkosty! I already tried to switch it off and on - no changes. Also, modifying the tikz code just works for one session. When saving the document and reopening it, the previews are not coming up again.

Comment: Dang, I'm not aware of any other workaround. I suggest to get in touch with the lyx-devel mailing list, or open a bug report at https://www.lyx.org/trac.